# Jquery toggle elements when button is clicked

Tags: jquery, each

I want to show the album name and category element when the corresponding button is pressed for that song. How do I do this? This is the jquery I have at the moment. Thanks for any help.

```
$('.song-list-btn').each(function(i, obj) {
    $(this).on('click', function () {

    });
});

foreach (var item in Model)
{
               <button class="song-list-btn" type="button">
                   <span class="fa fa-bars" aria-label="Song Details Menu"></span>
               </button>

                @Html.EditorFor(model => item.AlbumName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control details", @placeholder = "Album Name" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => item.AlbumName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

                @Html.EditorFor(model => item.Category, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control details", @placeholder = "Category Name" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => item.Category, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is here:
Next Adjacent Selector (“prev + next”)
http://api.jquery.com/next-adjacent-selector/

Comment: I give you link to documentation with examples. You didn't give html